# Querying with where, having and order by together in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table...

```
        ID      awaiting    approve decline      
        100       1         0         0     
        100       1         0         0     
        102       1         0         0     
        103       0         1         0     
        104       0         1         0     
        104       1         0         0     
        106       1         0         0     
        107       0         1         0     
        107       1         0         0     
        107       1         0         0
```

I have also the following code,...

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) total
    FROM
    (
    SELECT ID
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    AND MAX(awaiting = 1) > 0
    ) q
```

What the above code does is count all the ID repeated only twice and at least one of the ID awaititng=1,

But Now what I want is, I want to show the above results with their repeated ID listed if the awaiting is 1. (like ID 100).

From the above Query, The result is two (2) ID's 100 and 104, because we group by ID.

Now, how could I show all result from this ID's which has awaiting=1, even if the ID is the same (In this case we must have three list of rows)?

Help please....

Comment: Shouldn't 104 not come up, because it has 1 awaiting and another has a 0 awaiting?

Comment: yes, 104 should come...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM table1
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
             AND MAX(awaiting) = 1)
AND awaiting = 1
```

The results are:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ ID  ║ AWAITING ║ APPROVE ║ DECLINE ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 100 ║        1 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 100 ║        1 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 104 ║        1 ║       0 ║       0 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Ande [**here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7624/1) an sqlfiddle with a demo.

Comment: your answer is absolutely perfect, But did you realise takes some time for query to run...Could we make it some how faster? just question..

Comment: @MR.Test Well, I don't have the actual table to test this, so it's hard to realize if it takes time. But you do have the need to perform a subquery, so I'm guessing that the performance won't be too good without some well thought indexes

Comment: I have some query issue can i post new question, and you could see it for me please?

Comment: @MR.Test Of course that can post a new question (assuming is not a duplicated one), but I don't know if **I** can take a look to it. Don't worry though, there are plenty of users that can help you

Comment: @MR.Lamak if you don't see it I won't post it, because it is related to what you solve it now...so please tell me can you check it or not? Please?

Comment: I'm not sure, really. But if you do post it, and say on your question that it's a follow up from this question (and link to this Q there), then there shouldn't be any issue

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can get individual rows like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Awaiting, Table1.Approve, Table1.Decline
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  AND MAX(awaiting = 1) > 0
) q ON Table1.ID = q.ID
```

Note how your original query is used verbatim here because it returns all the `ID` values you want. The list of ID's is joined back to the original table to get the individual rows.

Comment: the problem with your answer is it returns all the ID's which is simplified from the above query, But what it should be is from the above query simplified-result...I need to get only those id's with awaiting=1 for each of them.

Comment: Sorry about that. @Lamak interpreted your question differently and provided a different answer. Does the Lamak answer work for you? If so, please let me know and I'll delete my answer. If not, could you edit the question and add expected results based on the sample data?

Comment: I think his answer is perfect, except i feel it runs slow...i don't know why?